# Collect API calls from multiple instances of a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, amazon-product-advertising-api

I've written a plugin which retrieves product info from the Amazon Product Advertising API via shortcode. When I retrieve the results from Amazon, I'm storing each individual product in a transient so that I don't need to make that particular call again. On most pages of my site which use this shortcode, it's only for a single product. But but in the case of one particular page I’m getting a `TooManyRequests` response because I'm using the shortcode 20 or 30 times.

The Amazon API allows me to pass in multiple products at a time, but I’m not sure how I could do that given I’m using multiple occurrences of a plugin.

Here's an example of how I'm calling the plugin right now.

```
[mm-productlinking id="1" template="image"]
```

Is there any way to collect multiple shortcode uses before execution, then call all of them at the same time? Perhaps something like this?

```
[mm-productlinking-group]
    some html code here
    [mm-productlinking id="1" template="image"]
    more html code here
    [mm-productlinking id="2" template="image"]
    and even more html code
[/mm-productlinking-group]
```

If I did something like this, I'd want it to be optional so that I wasn't forced to include the `mm-productlinking-group` outer shortcode.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would imagine that the `mm-productlinking-group` shortcode should have all the ids of the ads it should fetch and store them in memory. Then the `mm-productlinking` can go through the fetched results and get the result with the same id as is passed on the shortcode. `[mm-productlinking-group ids="1,2"][mm-productlinking id="1" template="image"][mm-productlinking id="2" template="image"][/mm-productlinking-group]`

Comment: You could make it so that if the id has not been stored that `mm-productlinking` fetches it itself.

Comment: Emiel, is it possible for a shortcode to function in both standalone *and* nested "mode"?

Comment: Sure. Like I mentioned the `mm-productlinking` can check if an id has been stored by the `group` shortocde, and if it is not, it can fetch it for itself, effectively making it "standalone". Alternatively you could add an attribute to the shortcode `mm-productlinking` to indicate wether it should rely on the `group` shortcode or not.

Comment: Oh, that's not a bad idea. Do you by chance have an example of shortcodes working together like that? The only plugins I've written so far only have "single use" functionality. Perhaps a blog post or open source example you could point me to?

Comment: Not from the top of my head no. If you include the code of your shortcode I'll try to make an example which implements the idea I suggested.

Comment: I added some code I wrote today as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm presenting is in many ways similar to @commadelimited's answer, but with a different approach to the structure and responsibilities.

### AmazonAdStorage class

I'd create a *singleton* which can be accessed from anywhere within the code. This class will function as a controller which is repsonsible for getting and storing the Amazon API data. Both the `mm-productlinking-group` and `mm-productlinking` shortcodes will use this class to fetch the items and get the items that have been fetched.

```
<?php

class AmazonAdStorage {
  private static $_instance = null;

  public static function get_instance()
  {
    if (self::$_instance === null) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$_instance;
  }

  private $amazon_api = new AmazonAPI(); // Replace this with the actual API

  // Storage for found items
  private $items = [];

  public function get_asins($ids) {
    // retrieves Amazon ASIN ID from post meta.
  }

  public fetch_items($ids)
  {
    $asins = $this->get_asins($ids);
    $results = $this->amazon_api->get_items($asins);
    array_merge($this->items, $results);
  }

  public fetch_item($id)
  {
    $asin = $this->get_asins($id);
    return $this->amazon_api->get_item($asin);
  }

  public get_stored_item($id)
  {
    if (!isset($this->$items[$id])) {
      return null;
    }

    return $this->$items[$id];
  }
}

function get_amazon_ad_storage()
{
  return AmazonAdStorage::get_instance();
}
```

### mm-productlinking-group

The group will have the responsibility of pre-fetching the ids that the children will be using. In contrast to your own solution, this implementation expects that the ids are passed as attributes. It will then fetch the ids and store them in the class.

```
<?php

add_shortcode('mm-productlinking-group', function ($atts, $content = null) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts([
    'ids' => '',
  ], $atts);

  $ids = explode(',', $atts['ids']);

  if (count($ids) === 0) {
    return $content;
  }

  $storage = get_amazon_ad_storage();
  $storage->fetch_items($ids);

  return do_shortcode($content);
});
```

### mm-productlinking

The child shortcode will access the same class and check if the `id` is found within the stored items in the class. If it is, use that result. If not, fetch the item from the API and then render the shortcode. This allows the `mm-productlinking` shortcode to function independently if needed.

```
<?php

add_shortcode('mm-productlinking', function ($atts, $content = null) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts([
    'id' => '',
    'template' => 'image'
  ], $atts);

  $id = $atts['id'];

  if ($id === '') {
    return '';
  }

  // Check if the id has been fetched and stored yet.
  $storage = get_amazon_ad_storage();
  $item = $storage->get_item($id);

  // No item has been found, fetch it manually.
  if ($item === null) {
    $item = $storage->fetch_item($id);
  }

  return '<div>' . $item['name'] . '</div>';
});
```

### Implementation

The usage should look like this:

```
[mm-productlinking-group ids="276357,276784,279208"]
  some html
  [mm-productlinking id="276357"]
  more html
  [mm-productlinking id="276784"]
  even more html
  [mm-productlinking id="279208"]
  html at the end
[/mm-productlinking-group]
```

#### Sidenote

I haven't been able to test the above and expect it needs some modification for it to work properly, like an actual implementation of the Amazon API.

Comment: This seems to be a more robust solution than mine. The main downside is that I would need to keep the list of IDs on the group shortcode, and the IDs on each child shortcode in sync. In the case of the specific page which caused me to do this rewrite there are 51 occurrences of the child shortcode.

Comment: Very true. The parsing option you suggested in your own solution is a pretty neat fix to counter the issue of keeping track of all of the ids in the parent. It's a style choice between being proactive and reactive.

Comment: Okay, I've got this working, but there's a downside to my approach. I retrieve the Amazon data, and store each in a transient. For 20 items, that's 2 API calls and 20 SQL inserts. Then I need to retrieve the transients, once for each child, that's 20 select statements; all on one page.

Do you know of any way to store the data "on" the parent (as part of the request), such that the child can just pluck it from the parent (in memory) instead of looking it up on its own?

Comment: Yes, that's what my approach does. It stores the API call results in the `$items` array of the `AmazonAdStorage` instance, which effectively keeps the results in memory. Each child can then select the item that belongs with them from `$items` array with the `get_item()` method. The important part of the `$items` array is that each API item is stored by it's id, eg: `"279208" => [...data], "275784" => [...data]` to fetch the items by id.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'll go back through your example and look more closely. The approach I took was to store the entire response in another transient. But I think your way is better because it avoids database <--> altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Emiel for the direction, this is what I came up with.

```
<?php

class Group {

    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode('group', array($this, 'run'));
    }

    function get_attribute_from_child_shortcode($content, $attribute) {
        // returns the post ID from each child shortcode contained in Group
    }

    function get_asins($post_ids) {
        // retrieves Amazon ASIN ID from post meta, for posts referenced in a child shortcode
    }

    function run($attributes = [], $content) {
        // only run when nested shortcodes are found
        if ($content) {
            $post_ids = $this->get_attribute_from_child_shortcode($content, 'id');
            $asins = $this->get_asins($post_ids);
    
            foreach (array_chunk($asins, 10) as $asin_group) {
                $amazon_results = $this->amazon_api->get_items($asin_group);
            }
    
            return do_shortcode($content);
        }
    }
}

class Linking {
    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode('mm-productlinking', array($this, 'run'));
    }

    function run($attributes = []) {
        $data_attributes = array_merge($data_attributes,[
            'product_info' => $this->amazon_api->get_item($game_meta['asin']),
        ]);
        return $data_attributes;
    }
}
```

It can be called like this

```
[mm-productlinking-group]
    some html
    [mm-productlinking id="276357"]
    more html
    [mm-productlinking id="276784"]
    even more html
    [mm-productlinking id="279208"]
    html at the end
[/mm-productlinking-group]
```

In which case I do the following:

- Grab the ID from each shortcode
- Look up the associated Amazon ID associated with that post ID
- Chunk the resulting Amazon IDs into groups of 10
- Call the Amazon API, store the results in a transient

It can also be called like this in which case the group functionality is not used.

```
[mm-productlinking id="277880"]
```

I'd love some thoughts on this approach as I've never done it before.